# Glue divs next to each other

Tags: css, web

Is there anyway to make divs sort of *glue* to each other no matter the size that they have?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Qqf.jpg

I've tried searching and the `float:left` works but for example in the image above the yellow div will make the brown and green not appear in the location like in the image, but below the line of the yellow.

I've tried using display: `inline-block` but it still doesn't work.

```
.glue-div{
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: orange;
    float: left;
    background: #303030;
}
```

here is a jfiddle that represents what my question is: http://jsfiddle.net/sezcY/

Simply look at div six positioning. It should be below three and it has a huge margin.

I guess I'd have to rearrange the order of the divs through JQuery?

Comment: Does [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) do what you want?

Comment: try http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Thank you both will look into it! ;)
I'm sorry that I didnt know about that, I didn't even know how to search for what I wanted. Guess I learned a new word: cascading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are inline, increase the size of the result pane and check it.

[image: Image showing they are inline]

However when the with of the screen or the body element decreases, few DIV element may move down

Fix to that problem

```
/* Mobile browsers only */
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   .newsletter_input {
        width: 320px;
    }
    .newsletter_input #form{
        font-size:42pt
    }
}
```

change the selectors

Answer (score 1):

If you want **two DIVs stick together**, put them **into two cells** (in one row or in two rows, as you like) **of one table** – they will keep their position to each other and won't drift apart, if you narrow down the window.